# on the side or at the side?

Tags: sentence-construction

**ObjectA    |fence|    ObjectB**

If I want someone to place objectC near the objectB (not attached to it), which of the following sentences are correct??

1. Install ObjectC at the ObjectB.
2. Install ObjectC by the ObjectB.
3. Install ObjectC at the side of the ObjectB.
4. Install ObjectC at the ObjectB side.
5. Install ObjectC on the ObjectB side.
6. Install ObjectC on the side of the ObjectB.

(I think 5 and 6 say Objectc is attached to the side of ObjectB.) Please teach me if there are any other ways to describe this positioning.
Thank you.

Comment: Note that _install_ implies rather more than _place_ - it means 'fix a piece of equipment in position'.

Comment: Thanks! How about mount or attach? Are they same as install?

Comment: You haven't told us what kind of objects A, B and C are. If they are some kind of machinery, you can _install_  them, or _mount_ them on the fence or some other kind of base. If you _attach_ one thing to another you fix it in place (it could be something like a notice).

Comment: I got it! thank you very much!

Comment: You haven't told us what kind of objects A, B and C are.  Please give us more details in your question. The answer will depend on what A, B and C are like.  In particular the word "install" may well not be appropriate.  Be **real**, don't make up something. Use the actual words that you need to use.

Comment: Without knowing what these objects are, this is a fool's errand [idiom].

Answer (score 0):

You said it correctly in your very first sentence:

**Install Object A *near* Object B.**

Instead of (3), you might say:

**Install Object A *beside* Object B.**

Do not use (1), (2), (4), (5) or (6).

You may also say "next to":

**Install Object A *next to* Object B.**

Comment: Thank you!!  I have one more question. When I want to talk about the space beside Object B, can I use the word "side"? like "right side" "my side"??

Comment: If C is on the same side of the fence as B, you could say it is 'on the B side of the fence'.

Comment: Thank you. So if C is an robot and B is an machine, can I say "The robot is on the machine side of the fence"?

Comment: **A** robot/machine. Yes, you could (assuming A is not a machine!).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @JiroF. The robot is on the machine-side of the fence.